# Linux qemu reset the register

Tags: linux, assembly, qemu

I program assembly under Linux, compile it and put it in a virtual flash:

```
dd if=myProgramm.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc

dd if=myProgramm.bin of=myProgramm.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc
```

Now I load the flash into the qemu emulator:

```
qemu-system-arm -M connex -pflash flash.bin -nographic -serial /dev/null
```

Here i can see the registers via

```
info registers
```

The problem is, when I now create a new flash, the old flash still is in the qemu emulator until i restart the emulator with

```
exit
```

and the Linux command `qemu-system`

How can I reload the flash without complete restart the whole emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for my understanding once you flashed the image in qemu you cannot update image.
suppose when you run any system using qemu which contains linux kernel zImage and rootfs with 
qemu-system-arm .... args. If u want to reboot it . the qemu quits and once again you have to laod with arguments.

So in qemu as for my knowledge u cannot reload the flash without complete restart the qemu.